# 2 highcharts conflict

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a [site](http://www.s-maof.com/Forum/blog.php?styleid=5) where I use highcharts. 
One place is the bottom indices bar. when you mouse over it, it generates a highchart graph.

The problem is on pages where a highschart graph is allready drawn and I draw another one Asyncronically (when mouse overing the indices line), The graphs are not drawn.
example: [here](http://www.s-maof.com/Forum/positions_map.php?style=5)

I [have read](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/275) where I have to disable the yaxis, and I did, It resolved the js error I was expirencing, but not the symptoms.

sorry i can't create a jsfiddle, the code is very long.

The steps to reprudce this error. 
1. Open the site in [here](http://www.s-maof.com/Forum/positions_map.php?style=5)
2. notice the graphs. 
3. mouse over the bottom line (red and green colors) to generate a graph.
4. notice the graphs disappear. 
5. Also notice , this problem does not occur in page without another highchart like [this](http://www.s-maof.com/Forum/blog.php?styleid=5) one.

Comment: if not a jsFiddle, could you post the exact steps to reproduce the issue in the aforementioned site? A little more clarity on the issue would be appreciated

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have added the steps to repruduce the isse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another div with the same id `graph` in an iframe that the page is using, hence its trying to render to that and seems to be failing, can you update your script to set the [renderTo](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#chart.renderTo) to point precisely to your `graph` div, as `$("#graphContainer#graph")[0]` and try?
[jsFiddle for object reference through jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/chart/renderto-jquery/)

Comment: thanks a bounch!! worked. changed the rentered element name to somthing else and it worked. :-)

Comment: don't change names at random like this, you may again fall prey to similar issue, use a more defined name as possible, #graphContainer#graph this will be less error prone as there will be very less possibility of another div with id `graph` inside a div with id `graphContainer`. I suggest you use at least a 2 level selector, but not like `div#graph` as this will still be collision prone